# Book class, appendix in toc appears as:" A appendix_name" . I would like to have only :"appendix_name" in the toc, without the letter related to it

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm writing a `book` class document and use the `appendix` package also. I'm having some problem with the table of contents and the appendix section that appears in the `ToC`. So, in the table of contents contents 
I have :

```
1 chapter_name
2 chapter_name
3 chapter_name
A appendix_name
B appendix_name
```

What I would like to have is instead :

```
1 chapter_name
2 chapter_name
3 chapter_name
appendix_name
appendix_name
```

I'm not able to remove the "A" and "B" letters from the `ToC`. Maybe because of the `book` class?

Anyone that can please help me with this problem?

Thanks very much,
Michele.

Edit1: I'm my thesis now I solved the problem but with this code the problem still exists. I'm still trying to understand differences between my thesis and the code that follows.

Edit2: I was freaking out but I found a workaround to the problem (but now I wouldn't say the problem is 100% solved). 
The trick is compile the code that follows, than comment the line `\backmatter` and recompile the code. In this way the first letter "A" and "B" disappeared. If you recompile for a second time the code with `%\backmatter` the problem of letters magically reappears!

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \cleardoublepage
   \mainmatter
   \chapter{Chapter 1}
   \lipsum
   \chapter{Chapter 2}
   \lipsum
   \chapter{Chapter 3}
   \lipsum
   \chapter{Chapter 4}
   \lipsum
   \backmatter
   \appendix
   \begin{appendix}
   \chapter[Appendix A]{Appendix A}
   \lipsum
   \end{appendix}
   \begin{appendix}
   \lipsum
   \chapter[Appendix B]{Appendix B}
   \end{appendix}        
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the minimal compilable version of your document that has this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @ilFuria: That's a question about one of those 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 `thesis` classes, most likely the solutions are not really compatible

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well, I tried with some minor tweaking and it works. ps: 1000000000? I thought there were more!

Comment: @ilFuria: Better? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer of course it did not work :(

Comment: @ilFuria: Your tweaking failed?

Comment: The update is nice but it is still not compilable. It's (1) not complete and (2) has `\input` statement for files nobody can access

Comment: okay I will upload the compilable version. how to mark the question solved?

Comment: @Michele: You can add the compilable version as self-answer as well.